# Accessing an element defined in a style's template in wpf?

Tags: wpf, templates, styles

I have a wpf `TabControl` which I added a `ScrollViewer` to. This is all wrapped into a style which is situated in a resource dictionary.

Now, on the window's xaml side, all I do is set 
    .

I would like to access the control viewer element, as defined in the style as follows:

```
<Style x:Key="MyTabStyle" TargetType="{x:Type TabControl}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TabControl}">
                 <ScrollViewer />
                        .......
```

How do I access the `ScrollViewer` which is so deeply nested in the hierarchy?

Answer (score 0):

Give it a name (theScrollViewer for instance), and use the FindName method to access it :

```
ScrollViewer scrollViewer = theTabControl.Template.FindName("theScrollViewer") as ScrollViewer;
```